# How to get only values from a list of dictionary and put them in a list again in Python?

Tags: python

I am running a query in the db and getting the output in a list of dict format. Each list of dict is associated with a id column.
Example:

```
[{'v_key':50},{'v_key':60}] # say here the id is 1
[{'r_key':10}] # here the id is 2 (the output go on like this and key in dict may not be same)
```

so to loop thru the output of the query i need something like below:

```
[50,60] # for id 1.(The values to be in a list and this will go on for all the id's)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[v for dct in lst for v in dct.values()]`. This will have undefined order if dicts have more than one value.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this! @Yakym

Answer (score 1):

If `query_result = [{'v_key':50},{'v_key':60}]`, then:

```
[d['v_key'] for d in query_result]  # [50, 60]
```

Comment: my program is somewhat dynamic and i can not hard code v_key in the python and the v_key can be changed based on the configuration. suppose for a id value 1 the key is v_key but for id value 2, the key may not be v_key and it could be r_key. But my end goal is to put all the values to put into a list (not the keys). @Claudia